# Understanding the proof for subsequences of convergent sequences converge to the same limit as the original sequence

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I found the following proof in Abbott's *Understanding Analysis* for the fact that the subsequences of a convergent sequence converge to the same limit as the original sequences:[image]

I do not understand when, in the second line, Abbott says $n_k \geq k$ $\forall k$. What exactly is $k$ here? Is this a typo? Should it read $n_k \geq n$ $\forall k$ instead? Thanks!

Comment: It is correctly mentioned in the book. $n_k \ge k \;\;\forall k$. Indexing of the original sequence is the set A={1,2,3,4,...,k,...}. Now to get the subsequence, you pick up elements from A -say for example 2,7, 12, 17,22, 27,... and then index them so you get $n_1=2, n_2=7, n_3=13 $ etc. Notice that every $n_k\ge k$. You may prove it rigorously using principal of mathematical induction.

Comment: @Koro Is $n$ indexing the set A or $k$?

Comment: Indexing A is  basically subscripts of the original sequence say $(a_n)=(a_1,a_2,a_3,..., a_k,...)$.  Now for example, consider the subsequence $(a_n) =(a_2,a_4,a_6,...)$ (subsequence made from even indices in A. How do you describe some mth term of this subsequence? You will index this set {$a_2,a_4,a_6...$} starting from 1st element, 2nd element and so on. This is done by introducing the index $n_{k}$. So index of first element in subsequence is $n_1$ (hence first element is $a_{n_1}$), of the second is $n_2$ (hence second element is $a_{n_2}$) and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$k$ is any positive integer. Then, $(n_k)_{k \geq 1}$ is an indexing of positive integers, which is strictly increasing. So for instance, when you take $n_1$, you can take any available positive integer, so trivially $n_1 \geq 1$. If $n_m \geq m$ for some positive integer m, then since $n_{m+1} > n_m$, we must have $n_{m+1} \geq m+1$ as well. So by induction, $n_k \geq k$ for all $k$.

Comment: Is the implication that $n_k \geq n$ hidden in the proof? How does this description of $k$ lead to the implication that "the same $N$ will suffice for the subsequence"?

Comment: $n_k$ doesn't actually have anything to do with $n$. Basically, the definition of $(n_k)_{k \geq 1}$ is simply a sequence of increasing positive integers (I could've equally called it $(m_k)_{k \geq 1}$ or something completely unrelated). The point is that if we index it by $k$, then the $k$-th term of our sequence can be related to $k$ in the way I described above. There is no implication for an arbitrary positive integer $n$. In the proof, it could've been made more clear that $|a_k-a| < \epsilon$ whenever $k \geq N$ instead of using $n$. But this is just dummy notation.